# My redux app needs state to be updated before it can contact the server, but this is not allowed in redux

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-redux

In my redux app I need to send a request to the server, but in order to build the payload for the request, I need the reducer to finish updating the state first (as this is the state I need to send).

This, however, is apparently not allowed in Redux (actions cannot be dispatched **in response to** an update of the state).  I'm keen to do this the "Redux way", but I can't work out how to architect it differently.  Please help.

Imagine an application (this is significant simplification of my app) where:

- users choose mathematical operations to apply (e.g. +2, *3, -1, etc.)
- these operations are always applied in order (e.g. (((0+2)*3)-1))
- the calculation itself, however, is calculated on the server (which is the core problem in this question)
- and when the server returns the result it is shown on the client

The app has 3 views (React components):

- AddOperationView (allows user to enter a new operation, e.g. '* 3', or '+ 2')
- ListOperationsView (lists all operations, e.g. [+2, *3, -1])
- ShowResultView (shows the result of the operations, e.g. "5")

Redux uses a single store, so the state of the app looks something like this:

```
{
  addOperation: {
    operator: '+',
    value: null /*user hasn't chosen a number yet*/
  },
  operations: {
    all: [
      {operator: '+', value: 2 },
      {operator: '*', value: 3 }
      {operator: '-', value: 1 }
    ]
  },
  result: {
    value: 5
  }
}
```

There are 3 reducers:

- AddOperationReducer (updates the state of the AddOperation view, and handles actions such as MULTIPLY_OP_SELECTED and NUMBER_SELECTED)
- OperationsReducer (updates the state of the Operations view, and handles actions such as APPEND_OPERATION and REMOVE_OPERATION)
- ResultReducer (holds the state of the Result view, and handles just one action: RESULT_RECEIVED_FROM_SERVER)

The flow:

- user chooses an operator (e.g. '+') and a value (e.g. 5) and then the APPEND_OPERATION action is fired
- OperationsReducer responds to this by appending the new operation to 'operations.all'
- The server is stateless (for the sake of argument) so, to calculate the result, we always need to send all the operations to the server (not just the latest one)
- Once the server returns, we fire the RESULT_RECEIVED_FROM_SERVER action, which the ResultReducer responds to by updating the state of 'result.value'

The problem:

- all redux documentation says I cannot perform an action (e.g. contact the server) *in response to*  the reducer updating the state (I have to do it *before* the reducer is invoked via a redux-thunk async action)
- but, until the OperationsReducer has updated the state, then I don't have a complete list of operations to send to the server
- of course, I could manually build the new list of operations in my action creator, but then surely aren't I just duplicating the work done by the OperationsReducer?

Questions:

- how can I trigger a server request **after** the OperationsReducer has finished updating the state?
- or should I be thinking about the problem differently?

Comment: Is APPEND_OPERATION the same action you want to fire something to the server? Wouldn't you already have the entire operations list in state by the time you want to fire a CALC_RESULT action or something?

Comment: @azium yes, ideally I would send the request to the server when the APPEND_OPERATION action is fired.  The problem is that the component that fires this action (the AddOperationView) only knows about the one Operation (so doesn't have access to the remaining state that the request would need)

Comment: @azium if I had a separate "calc result" button that the user clicked, then yes, this would be easily solved, as the state would already be there.  The problem is that I want the request to the server to happen automatically.

Comment: In this case I would use `componentWillReceiveProps` to trigger the new action in some top level component, like `<App />`, wrapped in some conditional statement to avoid an infinite loop. A very common scenario that your problem describes is fetching data from the server on route changes, except this time it's some other change.. same idea though.

Comment: Thanks @azium that worked.  I've taken the approach of having the OperationsReducer set a 'resultInvalidated' flag.  I then have a component that looks for this flag and if it is set it then dispatches an event to load data from the server (which resets the flag to prevent infinite loop).  Let me know if you were suggesting differently.

Comment: Sounds good to me. Happy coding!

Answer (score 2):

You can get the current state within a Redux thunk action creator. So you could do something like this:

```
// Component
dispatch(addOperator(myOperator));
dispatch(doArithmetic());

// Action creator
export default function doArithmetic() {
    return (dispatch, getState) => {
        const state = getState();

        return fetch.json(url, {
                method: 'post',
                body: {operators: state.operators}
            })
            .then((json) => {
                dispatch(arithmeticResponse(json.data));
            })
            .catch((error) => {
                dispatch(arithmeticResponseError());
            })
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

A clean solution would be to create the state needed for the server in the action handler, that means to produce the APPEND_OPERATION result in the action based on the current state and the parameters, dispatch to the store, call the server and dispatch with the server result.

To keep the code DRY you can either extract the mutation logic out of the reducer and share the logic with the action handler, or change the action type to something like SET_OPERATIONS and dispatch with the final value. Both approaches might be correct, it depends on the domain.

The fact that the local redux store and the server need the same data to perform their duties could be seen as merely coincidental.